# Delimiter in word splitting

Tags: bash

In Bash, word splitting is a step in command line processing. From Bash Manual

> The shell treats each character of $IFS as a delimiter, and splits the
>   results of the other expansions into words using these characters as
>   field terminators. If IFS is unset, or its value is exactly
>   `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>, <tab>,
>   and <newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of the previous
>   expansions are ignored, and any sequence of IFS characters not at the
>   beginning or end serves to delimit words. If IFS has a value other
>   than the default, then sequences of the whitespace characters space
>   and tab are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as long as
>   the whitespace character is in the value of IFS (an IFS whitespace
>   character). Any character in IFS that is not IFS whitespace, along
>   with any adjacent IFS whitespace characters, delimits a field. A
>   sequence of IFS whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter.
>   If the value of IFS is null, no word splitting occurs.

I want to rewrite the following example, so that the delimiter `space` between the arguments `a`, `b` and `c` is replaced with `tab` or `newline`

```
$ echo a b c
a b c
```

But when I hit the key `Tab`, there is no response.

When I hit `\` and `return`, there is no space between `a`, `b` and `c` in the output:

```
$ echo a\
> b\
> c
abc
```

Why can't I do what the quote says?

Btw, nothing comes out of `$IFS`:

```
$ echo $IFS
```

Comment: `echo $IFS` isn't going to tell you anything - by definition, you'll have no arguments.  You'll want to quote the expansion, and you'll want to see the whitespace characters - try `printf '%q\n' "$IFS"` instead.

Comment: `echo "$IFS" | od -bc` will show it.

Comment: You should focus on what you're trying to achieve as I don't think `$IFS` is meant for what you want.  It serves when you want to use non standard delimiters or remove some, which would impact every other commands run in that shell.

Comment: do you mean like `echo a$'\n'b$'\n'c` and `echo a$'\t'b$'\t'c` ?

Comment: @JuliePelletier: what is `$IFS` meant for, if not for what the quote says?

Comment: @JeffSchaller:  yes, but why did the ways I try not work?

Comment: If I was to guess, I'd say that bash's readline was "eating" it. Try `bash --noediting` then the echo test.

Comment: @Jeff: the tab example works but the newline example still doesn't.

Comment: presumably `readline` sees a newline as the end of the command; work around it with `echo '1<hit enter here>2<hit enter>3'` ? (single or double quotes to prevent readline from finishing the command). Or else I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @jeff: both single and double work the same. But the output is the argumetns delimited by newline instead of space.

Comment: then I think I misunderstand your goal. IFS is for Input, not for Output.

Comment: Indeed, IFS stands for _I_nput _F_ield _S_eparator, so.

Comment: @Jeff: No, you don't. My goal is to verify that the delimiters in IFS work, but since IFS doesn't control output delimiter, and I guess the default output delimiter for `echo` is space, I don't know why the output delimiter is changed by IFS.

Answer (score 4):

Newlines are handled specially by `bash`, regardless of the value of `IFS`.  A backslash before a newline causes the newline to be *ignored*.  Has nothing to do with word splitting and would occur even if `IFS` were set to some custom value.

From `LESS=+/^QUOTING man bash`:

> ```
>    A  non-quoted  backslash (\) is the escape character.  It preserves the
>    literal value of the next character that follows, with the exception of
>    <newline>.   If  a  \<newline>  pair  appears, and the backslash is not
>    itself quoted, the \<newline> is treated as a line  continuation  (that
>    is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).
> ```

You can see the word splitting on newline occur another way: By stuffing a newline into a variable, and then `echo`ing the variable without quoting it.

```
$ myvar=a$'\n'b$'\n'c
$ echo "$myvar"
a
b
c
$ echo $myvar
a b c
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## Direct answer

The *unquoted* command: `echo a b c`, will be split on (metacharacter space) no matter what `IFS` is or is not. The split arguments to `echo`: `a`, `b` and `c` will be printed with spaces because echo is defined as this:

```
LESS=+/'^ *echo \[-neE\] \[arg ...\]' man bash
```

> Output the args, separated by spaces, followed by a newline.

Also no `$IFS` involved.

So, what you quoted has no relevance here. The key part is:

> ... **splits the results of the other expansions into words** ...

You **must** have an expansion before `$IFS` is used.
There is not any expansion in `a b c`.

If you must have an effect of $IFS, use an unquoted expansion:

```
$ var='a   b   c'
$ echo $var
a b c
```

But that still does not use `$IFS` for output, only for splitting.

#### IFS in output.

Where `$IFS` does have relevance (for output) is in `$*`.

```
$ set -- a b c
$ IFS=$'\t'
$ printf '%s\n' "$*" | od -An -vtx1c
  61  09  62  09  63  0a
   a  \t   b  \t   c  \n
```

Is that what you need?

---

## Other issues.

#### Keyboard Tab

> when I hit the key Tab, there is no response

Then press together <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, release, and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

But without quotes you will not be able to assign a tab to a variable. Test:

```
$ var=a    b                  ### The space represents a tab as above.
bash: b: command not found
```

You will need:

```
$ var="a   b"                 ### The space represents a tab as above.
```

Double quotes at the very least.

#### Quote IFS

> nothing comes out of $IFS:

```
$ echo $IFS
```

Nothing comes out of `$IFS` because you did not quote `$IFS`. Try:

```
<user>$ echo "$IFS" | sed -n l
 \t$
$
<user>$
```

Which has one new line from `$IFS` and one from the command echo.
Better change to printf:

```
<user>$ printf '%s' "$IFS" | sed -n l
 \t$
<user>$
```

And use od:

```
$ printf '%s' "$IFS" | od -An -vtx1c
  20  09  0a
      \t  \n
```

As we already have a way to "see" what characters are contained in an string.
We may as well use that to "see" what is inside a couple of strings:

```
$ var='a b c'
$ echo "$var" | od -An -vtx1c
  61  20  62  20  63  0a
   a       b       c  \n
```

That should not be any surprise. As this (with single quotes) should not be:

```
$ var='a\
> b\
> c'
$ echo "$var" | od -An -vtx1c
  61  5c  0a  62  5c  0a  63  0a
   a   \  \n   b   \  \n   c  \n
```

Exactly what was typed. If the var is properly quoted, the backslash appear correctly.

#### Quoting

But quoting with double quotes may change some characters:

```
$ var="a\
> b\
> c"
$ echo "$var" | od -An -vtx1c
  61  62  63  0a
   a   b   c  \n
```

But what you wrote has no quotes on setting the var nor using it on echo.
That is a no-no rule in shells. Please **Quote correctly**.

Answer (score 0):

To replace a space with a tab character using `$IFS` you can use the argument array:

```
unset IFS
set a b c
IFS=$(printf \\t)
printf "%s\n" "$*"
```

Understand that `$IFS` is about splitting - it contains a list of characters the shell uses to split unquoted expansions in list contexts. You can't really use it to *replace* characters except in the special case of the `$*` special shell parameter. In all other cases its use will amount to *null*ifying and delimiting certain portions of unquoted shell expansions.

Comment: Aren't you stuffing arguments in a format string?  I mean, you just `set` them—but otherwise `printf "$*\n"` would be a pretty bad idea, no?

Comment: @Wildcard - Good point.