# Why does bash's readline eat tab?

Tags: bash

My question is from [Delimiter in word splitting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279778/delimiter-in-word-splitting?noredirect=1#comment486473_279778)

Why does Bash not respond when I hit `Tab` key?

What other keys  does Bash eat?

Comment: You have tab completion enabled.

Comment: "bash eats tab", now that is a very poor way to describe this. Also, I cannot figure out what use could you have for tab in a bash shell

Answer (score 3):

Wildcard likely [answered this one in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279876/why-does-bashs-readline-eat-tab#comment486569_279876) with:

> You have tab completion enabled.